# jQuery TableSorter Select [filter-options: option] and Group [child rows] Not Functioning at the same time

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a table where some rows have collapsible child rows and some columns have drop down menus to subselect certain categories.  I can get the sorting features to work when I just have rows with no child rows, but when I add the child rows, the select drop down does not work.  All rows in the table body disappear.  Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table Sort Internet Edit UPDATE</title>
    <LINK rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.blue.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.tablesorter.pager.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.2.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/parsers/parser-input-select.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/widgets/widget-grouping.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("table").tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            // hidden filter input/selects will resize the columns, so try to minimize the change
            widthFixed : true,
            sortList: [[1,0],[2,0]], 
            // initialize zebra striping and filter widgets
            widgets: ["group", "filter"],
            headers: {
              3: {sorter: "select" }
            },
            widgetOptions : {

            group_collapsible : true,  // make the group header clickable and collapse the rows below it.
            group_collapsed   : false, // start with all groups collapsed (if true)
            group_saveGroups  : true,  // remember collapsed groups
            group_saveReset   : '.group_reset', // element to clear saved collapsed groups
            group_count       : " ({num})", // if not false, the "{num}" string is replaced with the number of rows in the group
            //filter_childRows  : true,
            filter_childRows   : true,
            filter_cssFilter   : '',
            filter_hideFilters : false,
            filter_ignoreCase  : true,
            filter_reset : '.reset',                  
            filter_saveFilters : true,
            filter_searchDelay : 300,
            filter_startsWith  : false,
            filter_hideFilters : false,
            filter_functions : {
              3 : {
                    "Icon 1" : function(e, n, f, i, $r) { return /^[Option 1]/.test(e); },
                    "Icon 2" : function(e, n, f, i, $r) { return /^[Option 2]/.test(e); },
                    "Icon 3" : function(e, n, f, i, $r) { return /^[Option 3]/.test(e); }
                  }

            }//end filter functions
          }//end widget options
        });//end tablesorter

        $('.tablesorter-childRow td').hide();

        $('.tablesorter').delegate('.toggle', 'click' ,function(){
          $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:not(.tablesorter-childRow)').find('td').toggle();
          return false;
        });//end delegate

      });//end document ready
</script>

<style>
    #wrapper{width: 940px; margin: 0 auto;}
    .hiddenCol{border: 1pt solid black;}
    span{cursor: pointer;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead> 
    <tr> 
        <th class="Customer group-false" >Category</th> 
        <th class="group-false">Partner</th> 
        <th class="group-false">Application</th> 
        <th class="filter-select group-false" data-placeholder="Select All">Feature</th> 
    </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 

    <tr> 
        <td>EHR/POC Documentation</td> 
        <td>Azalea Health</td> 
        <td>Azalea EHR</td> 
        <td>Icon 1</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td>Provider-Provider Communication</td> 
        <td>Care Thread</td> 
        <td>Care Thread</td> 
        <td>Icon 2</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr class="toggle"> 
        <td><span>+ </span>EHR/POC Documentation</td> 
        <td>Cerner</td> 
        <td>PowerChart Touch</td> 
        <td>Icon 2</td> 
    </tr> 
  <!-- child row: when this is present, the select filter on the fourth [3] column does not work-->
      <tr class="tablesorter-childRow"> 
        <td class="hiddenCol" colspan="4">Cloud-based clinical documentation program. Personalized NoteFlow and Touch-Talk-Type functionality mirrors how clinicians think and intuitively improves productivity.</td> 
      </tr>

    <tr> 
        <td>EHR/POC Documentation</td> 
        <td>Clinically Speaking</td> 
        <td>CSpeak</td> 
        <td>Icon 3</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td>EHR/POC Documentation</td> 
        <td>Dataskill</td> 
        <td>ACUMI</td> 
        <td>Icon 1</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td>EHR/POC Documentation</td> 
        <td>Epic</td> 
        <td>Nuance Speech for Haiku and Canto</td> 
        <td>Icon 3</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td>EHR/POC Documentation</td> 
        <td>EvolveMed</td> 
        <td>Nuance ClU for Epic (v2014)</td> 
        <td>Icon 3</td> 
    </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```